# Normalize virtual property with API Platform

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm trying to return a virtual property with API Platform, but the only thing that I can get is the IRI.

I have multiple User, linked to multiple Organization. Those Organization have only one "Owner" (User class).

I want a property named "coach" which return the Owner of the first Organization

The case is a bit more complex but I simplified it.

App\Entity\User

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get"={"security"="is_granted('view', object)"},
 *      },
 *      normalizationContext={"groups"={"user", "user:read"}},
 *      denormalizationContext={"groups"={"user", "user:write"}}
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Groups({"user"})
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"user"})
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     * @Groups({"user"})
     */
    private $coach;

    /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->organizations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    [...]

    public function getCoach(): ?User
    {
        $coach = null;
        if (count($this->getOrganizations()) > 0) {
            $coach = $this->getOrganizations()->first()->getOwnerUser();
        }

        return $coach;
    }
}
```

I still getting

```
{
    email: xxx;
    firstName: xxx;
    organizations: [
       {
          name: xxx;
       },
       {
          name: xxx;
       }
    ],
    coach: "/api/users/4"
}
```

and I would like a proper User like

```
{
    email: xxx;
    firstName: xxx;
    organizations: [
       {
          name: xxx;
       },
       {
          name: xxx;
       }
    ],
    coach: {
       email: xxx;
       firstName: xxx;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is `coach` a self-referencing one2one relation?

Comment: Thanks for answering, yes it is

Comment: That doesn't seem logical. If `coach` is a one2one relation to itself, then the getter would normally return `$this->coach;` and you would have setter. Then it wouldn't be a virtual property. Which leads me to another conclusion. I'd say please try to  move the annotations from `$coach` directly to the method `getCoach` and see if there're any changes.

Comment: I checked the code of my past projects and I see that when serializing virtual properties I haven't used the annotation `@ApiProperty()`, just `@Groups({"group_name"})`.

Comment: How works `getOwnerUser()`? What does return?

Comment: Actually the coach should be a special logic and return an information that already exists in `Organization` that's why I don't really want to use doctrine relation. And it's a ManyToOne relation by the way @cezar, sorry.
`$this->getOwnerUser()` will `return a User`
The groups works but return only the IRI and not the whole object, that's the problem

Comment: Can I see getOwnerUser() function please?

Comment: According to this git issue https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/455 you can decoare the normalizer

Answer (score 1):

Just function with groups will be enough for Symfony 5

```
#[Groups(['user:read'])]
public function getCoach(): ?User
{
    $coach = null;
    if (count($this->getOrganizations()) > 0) {
        $coach = $this->getOrganizations()->first()->getOwnerUser();
    }

    return $coach;
}
```